# Why can I not assign this optional property a value in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am attempting to follow Microsoft's [EF tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/modules/persist-data-ef-core/4-interacting-data) but changing the data model to make sure that I understand the concepts. However, it seems like the compiler does not recognise my nullable property.

I have a model with four properties (code attached below) including the `Id`, with the last attribute in the model being nullable. Then, in the `Initialisation` function (database seeding), I then attempt to create two copies of the model, one with the last property set and one with it ignored, and add them both to the database with the `AddRange` function.

However, when I run `dotnet build` (to compile the thing), I get the following error:

> (filepath)/EntitySQL/Data/DBInitialiser.cs(22,45): error CS1513: } expected [(filepath)/EntitySQL/EntitySQL.csproj]

As soon as I comment out the initialisation of the variable, this and the other 16 syntax errors all go away!

How can I assign a value to this nullable object?

Code as promised:

*EntitySQL/Models/Article.cs*

```
namespace EntitySQL.Models;

public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<string> Paragraphs { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Video>? Videos { get; set; }     
}
```

*EntitySQL/Models/Video.cs*

```
public class Video
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Link { get; set; }
}
```

*EntitySQL/Data/DBInitialiser.cs*

```
using EntitySQL.Models;

namespace EntitySQL.Data
{
    public static class DBInitialiser
    {
        public static int Initialise(NewsContext context)
        {
            if (context.Articles.Any() || context.Videos.Any())
            {
                return 0;
            }
            
            Video video1 = new Video { Name = "Cat video", Link = "youtube cat videos.commm" }; //This link is fake
            Video video2 = new Video { Name = "Big Cat video", Link = "meowtube.com" }; //This link is fake
            
            Article bigCat = new Article 
                                 {
                                     Name = "World's Biggest Cat Spotted Outside McDonalds", 
                                     Paragraphs = new List<String>
                                                  {
                                                      "Residents said that the apocalypse was coming.",
                                                      "At about 3am this morning, locals were woken up to what sounded like an earthquake, as a cat-like animal was seen playing with the street lights as a toy.",
                                                      "The animal was about 6 metres tall and 30 metres long, filling up the entire carpark at McDonalds CityVille. Workers were terrified and police were called in to help though, understandably, they were clueless as to how to contain the furry beast."
                                                  },
                                     Videos = new List<Video>{ video1, video2 }; //This line is the problem!
                                };
            
            Article turtleHatch = new Article {
                Name = "A Turle Hatched",
                Paragraphs = new List<String>{
                    "Yesterday, at Snow White Beach, residents were treated to one of the most adorable sights some have ever seen",
                    "Two baby turtles were flapping their flippers on top of each other as they pushed with all of their might to reach the ocean",
                    "Despite the unusual time, the birds were successfully fended of by beachgoers who cheered as the turtles made it all the way to the ocean."
                }
            };
                        
            context.Articles.AddRange(new List<Article> { bigCat, turtleHatch });
            context.SaveChanges();

            return 0;
        }
        
        public static int CreateDbIfNotExists(this IHost host)
        {
            using (IServiceScope scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                IServiceProvider provider = scope.ServiceProvider;
                NewsContext context = provider.GetRequiredService<NewsContext>();
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();
                Initialise(context);
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `;` from this line:

```
 Videos = new List<Video>{video1, video2}; //This line is the problem!
```

U cant use `;` in object initialization block. U can just simply use `,` to separate property iniations.

VisualStudio is weak on finding this error. so it generates a lots of confusing errors.